# Is it possible to implement a loop in mysql query

Tags: mysql

Hi there i have a table:

**Teams:** as below

```
|Team ID  | Member ID|
| 1       |  10       |
| 2       |  230      |
| 1       |  11       |
| 4       |  56       |
| 1       |  15       |
| 2       |  236      |
| 1       |  18       |
| 3       |  43       |
| 1       |  17       |
```

I did this to find the members of a team:

SELECT members from teams where team_ID = 1; and it gave me 10,11,15,18,17

**I have a different table for each member** .So I tried something like this to fetch the data from different tables and it worked fine:

```
SELECT * FROM 10
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 11
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 15
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 18
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM 17
```

Is it possible to make this **2 Queries into 1 Query** because the members of a team changes dynamically....

Any help please...

Let me be bit more clear: My final result should only contains data from different **member** tables. Hope I am clear..

Comment: *you have a different table for each member?*  Sounds like a bad design.  If you need to perform a loop, take a step back and reconsider your table design. You should not have to loop to get data from your database.

Comment: I know but for some reasons i made it like that... I cant change it now

Comment: If you can't change it then your database is probably doomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I ***strongly advise*** that you consider a redesign of your table structure otherwise you will have a difficult time querying this data.

You can do something like this though. Of course, this only works if you know the tables member tables that you want to query:

```
select *
from teams t
left join
(
  SELECT *, 10 Member 
  FROM 10
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * , 11 Member 
  FROM 11
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * , 15 Member 
  FROM 15
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * , 18 Member 
  FROM 18
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT * , 17 Member 
  FROM 17
) m
  on t.memberid = m.member
```

If you want to do this dynamically, then you might be able to use a prepared statement similar to this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'select *, ',
      MemberID,
      ' AS Member from ', MemberID, '
       '
    )
  separator ' union all ') 
  INTO @sql
FROM teams
WHERE TeamID = 1;

SET @sql = CONCAT('select *
                   from teams t 
                   left join
                   (', @sql, ' ) m
                     on t.memberid = m.member');

-- select @sql

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Why use a string (rather than an integer) type for the literal `Member` column?

Comment: Although your solution works, giving the OP any hope on his failed attempt is counter productive.

Comment: @Clodoaldo I completely agree, the current table structure is awful.

Comment: HI bluefeet thanks for the suggestion and help... Apologies if i am not clear in my question because i dont have a table named member..but it have different table for each member like d1_gps for 1 and d2_gps for 2 and so on.. SO i m thinking to fetch all the members of a team in as array and use this for querying... am i doing it right

Comment: @DomincJune You can try to do it that way but your design is incredibly bad and is going to continue to cause you problems to query.

Comment: HI there your query is working... sooner i ll try to change the structure of the table .. thank You

Answer (score 0):

it can be done by  `strored procedure or function` ,

write function and get the count of the MEMBER,  based on the count construct the loop will be executed 
use  `temp`  to stored the result.

in  `PostgreSQL`  dynamic query construct can be execute by using  `EXECUTE`